# UIBarButtons styled with System Items, disappear after rotation

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

In our app the initial ViewController is embedded in a regular Navigation Controller. We have two UIBarButtons, located in the upper right of the navigationbar. One of the buttons is styled with a custom image and the other one with the camera icon from the provided System Items.

Here is the problem:
When the app starts in portrait, both bar buttons are visible. After rotating the device to landscape, the UIBarButton with the camera symbol disappears and no longer shows up when rotating back to portrait again.

I have no outlets to neither the navigationbar nor the UIBarButtons, no adjustments in code are made whatsoever.

The button that disappears after rotation still exists in the navigationbar, if you tap where it is supposed to be shown, the action is triggered. It seems to only be the image that is removed for some reason. And only if the button is styled with any of the System Items.

Can anyone think of a reason why this problem occurs?

Comment: can you provide some code of adding both bar button on the navigation bar?

Comment: The buttons are not added in code, they are added in the Interface Builder. The buttons have no outlets, the only difference between them is that the buttons with System Items become invisible after rotation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this problem was related to appearance proxy code that I had in my appDelegate:

```
[[UITextField appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
[[UITextView appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
```

Apparently these two statements affect the behaviour of the barbutton appearance. I cannot see why, but I am sure that there is a good reason.

Getting rid of these two statements in the appDelegate solved the problem.